# Excel VBA Selenium - Image Click

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

https://www.laquintaca.gov/connect/short-term-vacation-rentals

The site above has a cluster of images.  On of those images is a box with the text value "ACTIVE AND SUSPENDED PERMITS".  Click on the image takes you to a PDF that is downloadable.   I would like to automate that download process to my desktop. The "orange" image stays the same but the href address changes every two weeks(document serial number on the end) when they upload a new PDF.

More directly, How do i click on the orage image space to get to the underlying, but bi-weekly changing PDF?

I can not find the actionable object address to click to take me to the downloadable document.  What is the VBA Selenium code line to "click"

'*****************************************************************************

```
Sub FindingElements()

    Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver 
    cd.Start

    cd.Get "https://www.laquintaca.gov/connect/short-term-vacation-rentals"
    '"https://www.laquintaca.gov/connect/short-term-vacation-rentals"
    
'=================================================================
'Find Element By ID or Name
'=================================================================
    Dim SearchInput As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim SearchButton As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
'
    If Not cd.IsElementPresent(FindBy.ID("OuterContainer")) Then
        MsgBox "Could not find search input box"
       Exit Sub
    End If
'
'    Set SearchInput = cd.FindElementById("OuterContainer")
'    Set SearchInput = cd.FindElement(FindBy.ID("searchInput"))
'    Set SearchInput = cd.FindElementByName("search")
'    Set SearchInput = cd.FindElementByCss("#searchInput")
'    Set SearchInput = cd.FindElementByCss("[name='search']")
'    Set SearchInput = cd.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='searchInput']")
```

Comment: I don't find _box with the text value "ACTIVE AND SUSPENDED PERMITS"_

Comment: Well, I can't help you with the VBA but sure with Selenium. The XPath to the button you need is: `//img[@alt='ACTIVE & SUSPENDED PERMITS BOX'` use the `ByXPath` method and then use `Click()` at the end, it should be something like this:  `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@alt='ACTIVE & SUSPENDED PERMITS BOX']")).Click();`

EDIT: Me aware that you gonna need to switch to the newly opened tab (maybe use index for that or capture the link inside the button and open a new tab) to then latter save as PDF.

Comment: Did Not Work (ExcelVBA- Selenium)    'Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
'Private cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver
'cd.Get 
"https://www.laquintaca.gov/connect/short-term-vacation-rentals"
'Sleep 2000
'cd.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@alt='ACTIVE & SUSPENDED PERMITS BOX']")).Click

Comment: "ACTIVE AND SUSPENDED PERMITS" is a button, but no button or object reference - that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS or XPath. I prefer CSS because XPath is more complex and sometimes slower than CSS.

The first procedure waits until the file is downloaded.

I used a procedure by **Paul_Hossler** to find the **ChromeDownloadFolder**.

```
Sub DownloadFileFromLaquintaca()
    Dim cd As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim DefaultChromeDownloadFolder As String
    
    ' Get Chrome download folder
    DefaultChromeDownloadFolder = ChromeDownloadFolder
    
    ' Start Chrome
    cd.Start
    
    ' Navigate to
    cd.Get "https://www.laquintaca.gov/connect/short-term-vacation-rentals"
    
    Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
    Dim imgElement As Selenium.WebElement
            
    ' Check if element is present with CSS
    If Not cd.IsElementPresent(FindBy.Css("img[alt='ACTIVE & SUSPENDED PERMITS BOX']")) Then
        MsgBox "Could not find image box"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Click to download
    cd.FindElementByCss("img[alt='ACTIVE & SUSPENDED PERMITS BOX']").Click
    
    ' Wait until download is completed
    Do While Dir(DefaultChromeDownloadFolder & "\" & "STVRCurrentActiveSuspended.pdf") = ""
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub

Function ChromeDownloadFolder()
    ' By Paul_Hossler 
    Dim sPref As String
    Dim iFile As Long, iStart As Long, iEnd As Long
    Dim sBuffer As String, sSearch As String, sDownloads As String

    ' Chrome preferces file, no extension
    sPref = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"
    
    ' marker
    sSearch = """download"":{""default_directory"":"

    ' read the whole file into buffer
    iFile = FreeFile
    Open sPref For Input As #iFile
        sBuffer = Input$(LOF(iFile), iFile)
    Close #iFile

    ' find start of marker
    iStart = InStr(1, sBuffer, sSearch, vbTextCompare)
    
    ' find comma
    iEnd = InStr(iStart + Len(sSearch), sBuffer, ",", vbTextCompare)

    ' pull out path
    sDownloads = Mid(sBuffer, iStart + Len(sSearch) + 1, iEnd - iStart - Len(sSearch) - 2)

    ' remove double back slashes
    ChromeDownloadFolder = Replace(sDownloads, "\\", "\")
End Function
```

Comment: Elio - Thank you much!!  I have labored over this for days.  Only one issue.   the code stops and errors out at " Open sPref For Input As #iFile"

Comment: perhaps I loaded this line incorrectly

Comment: ' remove double back slashes

    ChromeDownloadFolder = Replace(sDownloads, "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop", "STVRDownload")

Comment: When I comment out the functioon everything works, so I sat up a download folder D:\MyDownloads   and set the pointer in line there, but still it blows up

Comment: Since the problem is only in the download function, If there was somewhere where I could capture the final URL location of the file, I can figure out how to download it (The total file and location changes every two weeks)

Comment: The code I posted was tested and it works. Update your code and show us that you are running at the moment.

Comment: I solved the problem this way - thank you so much for your help:

Comment: your code worked perfectly.!!  The error I get is in the Function by Mr. Hossler.  It blows up at:  "Open sPref For Input As #iFile"   as a fix I tred to change my file download location to "D:\MydownLoads" but still no good in the function.   Thnks for your code that solved my big problem!!   I will monkey with the Function code.

Comment: If my answer was useful you could check it, yes?

Comment: Yes it was fantastic. You helped me over a big hump.  Sorry I am new to this, gladly clicked yes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue I was having with the SUB below that works perfectly.  Thank you so much for you fantastic help.  The code blow swithces to the Current code tab, reds the URL then downloads to a location via the WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") process:

```
Sub DownloadFileFromLaquintaca2()
    Dim cd As New selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim DefaultChromeDownloadFolder As String
    Dim MyURL As String
    
    ' Start Chrome
    Set cd = New ChromeDriver
    cd.Start
    
    ' Navigate to
    cd.get "https://www.laquintaca.gov/connect/short-term-vacation-rentals"

    Const URL = "https://www.laquintaca.gov/connect/short-term-vacation-rentals"
    
    Dim FindBy As New selenium.By
    Dim imgElement As selenium.WebElement
            
    ' Check if element is present with CSS
    If Not cd.IsElementPresent(FindBy.Css("img[alt='ACTIVE & SUSPENDED PERMITS BOX']")) Then
        MsgBox "Could not find image box"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    cd.FindElementByCss("img[alt='ACTIVE & SUSPENDED PERMITS BOX']").Click
       
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
    
    'Get URL Address in Second Chorme Tab
          With cd
            '.get URL
            .SwitchToNextWindow
            MyURL = .URL
            'Debug.Print .Window.Title
            'Debug.Print myURL
            .Windows.Item(.Windows.Count - 1).Close 'close prior window
        End With
    
    'Write PDF File into Location with file Name STVR.PDF ---D:\MyDownLoads\STVR.pdf
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", MyURL, False, "username", "password"
    WinHttpReq.send
    
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile "D:\MyDownLoads\STVR.pdf", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If
 
End Sub
```